# iMessage Deletion from physical device

Tags: iphone, messages

How long are iMessages that are not backed up to the cloud, but are deleted stored on the physical device of an iPhone X (12.4). Are these physically deleted or still available in the unallocated space of the device and recoverable from SQL or another code script - the message i'm looking for is around 1.5 months old?

Comment: Yes, messages are stored on your phone for a while after you delete them, however I’m not sure for how long. I forget exactly how I located them in the past but you can extract them via plain text from a non encrypted iOS backup stored on your Mac. Most importantly you should create a backup via iTunes (finder for Mojave) as soon as possible. The folder will be in something like ~/Library/Application Support/Mobile Sync/Backup. You can search the contents of the files within the folder for things you are looking for such as numbers or phases from present texts.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-long-does-an-iphone-store-a-deleted-sms) it is two years. There are some tools that offer services like this by plugging your iPhone into your computer if you search around.